# How to use wildcard for strings (matching and replacing)?

Tags: c++, string, wildcard, match

I want to search for a number of letters including `?` replaced by a letter matched in a string in C++.

Think of a word like `abcdefgh`. I want to find an algorithm to search for an input `?c` for any letter replaced by `?`, and finds `bc`, but also it should also check for `?e?` and find `def`.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a good case for *regular expressions*, now part of the standard library in `<regex>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to support `?`, that's pretty easy: when you encounter a `?` in the pattern, just skip ahead over one byte of input (or check for `isalpha`, if you really meant you only want to match letters).

Edit: Assuming the more complex problem (finding a match starting at any position in the input string), you could use code something like this:

```
#include <string>

size_t match(std::string const &pat, std::string const &target) { 

    if (pat.size() > target.size())
        return std::string::npos;

    size_t max = target.size()-pat.size()+1;

    for (size_t start =0; start < max; ++start) {
        size_t pos;
        for (pos=0; pos < pat.size(); ++pos)
            if (pat[pos] != '?' && pat[pos] != target[start+pos])
                break;
        if (pos == pat.size())
            return start;
    }
    return std::string::npos;
}

#ifdef TEST
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    std::cout << match("??cd?", "aaaacdxyz") << "\n";
    std::cout << match("?bc", "abc") << "\n";
    std::cout << match("ab?", "abc") << "\n";
    std::cout << match("ab?", "xabc") << "\n";
    std::cout << match("?cd?", "cdx") << "\n";
    std::cout << match("??cd?", "aaaacd") << "\n";
    std::cout << match("??????", "abc") << "\n";
    return 0;
}

#endif
```

If you only want to signal a yes/no based on whether the whole pattern matches the whole input, you do pretty much the same thing, but with the initial test for `!=` instead of `>`, and then basically remove the outer loop.

Comment: @Alex: Do you only want it to signal a match if the pattern matches the whole string, or do you want (for example) `?abc` to match against `xxxabc`, and tell you that it matched starting at the third position?

Answer (score 2):

How about using boost::regex? or std::regex if you're using c++11 enabled compilers.

Comment: actually, i am using xcode. is there a better way using string functions(substr etc)?

Comment: Full featured pattern matching is not easy to implement but it will be far much easier if '?' is the only thing you need.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you insist on "wildcards" in the form you exhibit the term you want to search for is "glob"s (at least on unix-like systems).

The c-centric API is to be found in `glob.h` on unix-like systems, and consists of two calls `glob` and `globfree` in section 3 of the manual.

Switching to full regular expressions will allow you to use a more c++ approach as shown in the other answers.